# How to access LaTeX counters in luatex?

Tags: luatex

In the same vein as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328781/how-to-access-latex-lengths-in-luatex), I know I can access raw TeX counts with Lua using `tex.count[key]`, but how do I access a LaTeX counters in Lua?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This is TeX
\newcount\mycount
\mycount 4\relax
% end of TeX

\newcounter{mycountlatex}
\setcounter{mycountlatex}{5}

\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.print(tex.count['mycount'])}  

% How to do something like this?
% \directlua{tex.print(tex.count['mycountlatex'])}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: please fix your example, which generates `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mycountlatex 
              
l.8 \newcounter{\mycountlatex}` (latex counters have no `\ ` in the name.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTeX counters can be accessed as TeX counts, but LaTeX prepends the name with a `c@` so `mycountlatex` becomes `c@mycountlatex` in TeX ([source](http://www.texdev.net/2009/11/17/tex-counts-and-latex-counters/)).

This means the MWE above would become:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This is TeX
\newcount\mycount
\mycount 4\relax
% end of TeX

\newcounter{mycountlatex}
\setcounter{mycountlatex}{5}

\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.print(tex.count['mycount'])}  

% How to do something like this?
\directlua{tex.print(tex.count['c@mycountlatex'])}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: No. This generates the same error as the noted in the comment under the question.

Comment: Now tested and fixed.

Answer (score 6):

It is a good idea to hide such internal details from the user and define a `latex.counter` that "does the right thing(tm)".  This is relatively easy to do in Lua using metatables:

```
latex = latex or {}
latex.counter = latex.counter or {}

local counter = latex.counter
local count = tex.count

setmetatable(counter, {__index = function(t, key) 
    return count['c@' .. key]
  end} )
```

Now `latex.counter[key]` will return the value of the LaTeX counter `key`. Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
latex = latex or {}
latex.counter = latex.counter or {}

local counter = latex.counter
local count = tex.count

setmetatable(counter, {__index = function(t, key) 
    return count['c@' .. key]
  end} )
\end{luacode*}

% This is TeX
\newcount\mycount
\mycount 4\relax
% end of TeX

\newcounter{mycountlatex}
\setcounter{mycountlatex}{5}

\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.print(tex.count['mycount'])}  

% How to do something like this?
\directlua{tex.print(latex.counter['mycountlatex'])}  

\end{document}
```