# Lualatex, deal with tcolorbox in Lua

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox

I would like to try to use lualatex in order to use as little as possible Tex code (mostly because it's unreadable, and overcomplicated). I understand that, because some libraries are coded in Tex, I can't avoid to write a few 'tex.sprint', but I'd like to use the fewer I can.

So here is what I'd like to do: define a function in lua that creates a `tcolorbox`, and get on lua side the dimension of the box, in order to display, for example, a picture, or any code I'd have written in lua.

MWE:

test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \directlua{dofile("file.lua")
    displayPicInTCbox("simpson.jpg")
}  
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

file.lua

```
function displayPicInTCbox(filename)
   tex.sprint([[\begin{tcolorbox}]])
   -- This works, but I'd like to use my own lua function, so can't use it
   tex.sprint([[\includegraphics[width=\tcbtextwidth]{simpson.jpg}]])
   img.write({ filename = "simpson.jpg";
           -- This does not work
           width=tex.dimen['tcbtextwidth']
           -- Same problem
           -- width="\\tcbtextwidth"
   })
   tex.sprint([[\end{tcolorbox}]])
end
```

Thank you! By the way, if you have any advice to replace TeX with Lua, please tell me!

Comment: `tcolorbox` is a quite large package with tons of options and features, and it uses `pgf` which is also a large package with lots of options. You need a better argument than "I don't like tex code" if someone should rewrite all this in lua for you. If you want to see how output can be generated only with lua check the code  of the speedata publisher: https://download.speedata.de/publisher/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ok thank you. Of course I don't ask to rewrite the great tcbox package, I just wanted to know if it was possible to recover in lua some "environment variable" on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\tcbtextwidth` is macro not a length. You can't access tex macros from inside lua, so you should either store it in a length (skip) or expand it before passing to lua:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newlength\lualen{}

\begin{luacode}
function insertimageA ()
img.write({ filename = "example-image-A.pdf",width=tex.skip['lualen'].width})
end

function insertimageB (imgwidth)
img.write({ filename = "example-image-A.pdf",width=imgwidth})
end
\end{luacode}


\begin{document}%
\begin{tcolorbox}

\setlength\lualen{\tcbtextwidth}
\directlua{insertimageA()}

\directlua{insertimageB("\tcbtextwidth")}   
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok great, thank you for the "skip" tips. I'm not sure however to understand the difference between tex.dimen['lualen'] and tex.skip['lualen'].width...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328784/2388.